# pytorch-kaldi timit tutorial error shared_list[0] IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: pytorch, runtime-error, kaldi

```
# ***** Reading the Data********
if processed_first:

#Reading all the features and labels for this chunk
shared_list = []

p = threading.Thread(target=read_lab_fea, args=(cfg_file, is_production, shared_list, output_folder))
p.start()
p.join()

data_name = shared_list[0]
data_end_index = shared_list[1]
fea_dict = shared_list[2]
lab_dict = shared_list[3]
arch_dict = shared_list[4]
data_set = shared_list[5]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2A8J.png)

- First I did run kaldi's run.sh file
- When I did that, I corrected cmd.sh's contents.
- Original --> call queue.pl
- to --> call run.pl
- Because I met bug when i run original source
- Reference : https://www.google.com/url?q=https://groups.google.com/g/kaldi-help/c/tokwXTLdGFY?pli%3D1&sa=D&source=editors&ust=1631002151871000&usg=AOvVaw1FYQHJEmI-kkAAeAB2tcKt
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAjN9.png)

I found that fea_dict and lab_dict in data_io.py has no shared element. How can I progress the TIMIT tutorial experiments?

I'm doing experiment using cfg/TIMIT_baselines/TIMIT_MLP_mfcc_basic.cfg file. Just correcting absolute directory of linux.

Answer (score 0):

I refered https://github.com/mravanelli/pytorch-kaldi/issues/185

run copy-feats.
I saw--> kaldierror::KaldiFatalError